# Issue with verifying JWT token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I have a express nodejs backend which has three URL functions in which

1) registerUser() added user details to database and provided a JWT for the caller

2) verifyToken()- verifies if the JWT is valid

3) getConfiguration()- if JWT is verified from above function provides user with some configuration data

So the express code I'm using to achieve this is

```
//Routes.js

app.use(requestIp.mw())

app.route('/register')
    .post(userController.registerUser);

app.use(userController.verifyToken)

app.route('/user/configuration')
    .post(chayakkadaController.getConfiguration);
```

Now my issue is whenever I try calling the URL /register instead of calling registerUser function it calls verifyToken and says my token is invalid ( I want registerUser function to work without token, but getConfiguration should work only with token)

This is my verifyToken function

```
export function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
var token = req.body.token || req.headers["token"];
var appData = {};
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            appData["status"] = 1;
            appData["error"] = "Invalid Token";
            res.status(500).json(appData);
        } else {
            req.user = decoded;
            next();
        }
    });
} else {
    appData["status"] = 1;
    appData["error"] = "Need access token";
    res.status(403).json(appData);
}
}
```

My register User code

```
export function registerUser(req, res) {
let userData = {
    device: req.body.device,
    device_version: req.body.device_version,
    device_id: req.body.device_id,
    app_version: req.body.app_version,
    app_id: 2,
    ip_address: req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress
}
database.query(`INSERT INTO users SET ?`, userData)
    .then(result => {
        let user = {
            id: result.insertId
        }
        let token = jwt.sign(user, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
        let appData = {};
        appData["token"] = token;
        redis.sendMessage({
            qname: 'registration_queue',
            message: result.insertId + '',
        }, (err, resp) => {
            res.status(201).json(appData);
        });

    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json("Database Error");
    })
}
```

Comment: Is `userController.registerUser` calling `next`? Can we see it?

Comment: @Rashomon added code

Comment: are you hitting `/register` with a POST request? if you hit it with a GET, the route won't match so it will go to the next middleware, which is `verifyToken`.

Answer (score 0):

Why you wanna to invent the wheel? there is a NPM module for that:
[express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

It has middleware that checks the jwt, if it **valid**, it decodes the payload and adds it to the request after that it proceed to your controller, if it is **not valid**, it throws an error, that you should catch, and do what ever you want.

It has the `unless` feature, so you can configure the entire subpath as restricted unless it is `/register`

```
router.use(`admin/`, [
  expressJwt({ secret: jwtSecret }).unless({
    path: ['/register]
  }),
]);
```